# What is the problem with my discord.js code?

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I wrote the code related to the permission section of the bot and that code is correct, but after a few minutes the bot gives an error and does not work. this error
[image]

Because the number of codes is so high I can not write it here but I can leave the part that is an error

```
        if(command.permissions.length){
      let invalidPerms = []
      for(const perm of command.permissions){
        if(!validPermissions.includes(perm)){
          return console.log(`Invalid Permissions ${perm}`);
        }
        if(!message.member.hasPermission(perm)){
          invalidPerms.push(perm);
        }
      }
      if (invalidPerms.length){
        return message.channel.send(new Discord.MessageEmbed() .setDescription('<a:poker:840226458566918185> You do not have access to this command! this command for \`${invalidPerms}\`') .setColor('RED'));
      }
    }
```

Comment: We don't know what `commands` is supposed to be, without any code we can't really help you.

Answer (score 0):

I would believe, that your bot is not authenticating on the server, and the permissions are not arriving.

You should be set a console.log to permissions and debug.